# Can Visual Studio Code be installed in a Virtual Machine that runs Debian OS?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debian, virtualbox

I've set up a virtual machine on my windows 10 laptop. The VM uses the Raspberry pi Buster OS.
It works OK. I can replicate the RPI user GUI, etc

Then I have installed several python libraries. E.g numpy, opencv-python, pillow, etc.

I would like to use the Microsoft Visual Studio IDE in that VM, as part of my efforts to code and de-bug software prior to running the code on a real RPI4 board.

Is it possible to install VS code into the above VM ?

sudo apt install code just comes back with "unable to locate package code".

Many thanks,
Robert

Comment: I am running VS Code on my Debian based Linux. I downloaded deb-package from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

Comment: You cannot find it from Debian default repositories.

Comment: Many thanks to ex4 for the above comment. How can VS code be installed in my VM ?

Comment: Check this tutorial. it's very easy https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-the-code-server-cloud-ide-platform-on-debian-10